# Android Random Text Widget

Tags: android, string, class, random, widget

I'm a beginner in Android programming.

I'm wondering .. what would the code in the class look like for a widget that simply displays a random string every once in a while (from like a list of 10 strings)?

I understand the rest of how to make the widget, just not the class.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you will need to refer to using the [Java Random class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html)

You would start off by gaining access to the random class by

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
```

Next you will need to get references to the string by a number for each string. The Random class link should help with that. Also [Check here](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=62)

You would then loop the method using for().

Its a pretty simple concept just takes a little bit of logic.